# How to type HOC which extends wrapped component's props?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I wrote a HOC that adds the attribute 'data-testid' to the given component to facilitate simpler testing.

```ts
function withTestId(Component: React.ComponentType<any>, testId: string) {
  Component.propTypes = {
    ...Component.propTypes,
    'data-testid': PropTypes.string,
  }

  Component.defaultProps = {
    ...Component.defaultProps,
    'data-testid': testId,
  };

  return Component;
}
```

It works by extending the `propTypes` and `defaultProps` attribute of the given component.

But I can't figure out how to correctly add a typescript return type.

As soon as I do something like so:

```ts
type WithTestId<T> = T & { 'data-testid': string };

function withTestId<PROP_TYPES>(Component: React.ComponentType<PROP_TYPES>, testId: string):
    React.ComponentType<WithTestId<PROP_TYPES>> {
```

I get errors like so:

> Type '{ 'data-testid': PropTypes.Requireable; }' is not assignable to type 'WeakValidationMap<PROP_TYPES>'.

and

> TS2322: Type '{ 'data-testid': string; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<PROP_TYPES>'.

I would prefer not to have to cast `as any`, but I'm not seeing another solution.

Comment: what is PROP_TYPES ?

Comment: `PROP_TYPES` is an arbitrary name for a generic which is sent to `ComponentType`